# Как подписать httpWebRequest с помощью сертификата .crt и .key

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно сделать http запрос в с# с сертификатом и приватным ключом. В Postman это выглядит так и прекрасно работает.

[image]
Сами ключи имеют вид

.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEkzCCA3sFuCKwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQKTNSAwgYwxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJVMRAwDgYD
....
yBqyGsWijaPpFvXv8QGRnopBPTLFwXw=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

.key

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS0wggkpAgEAAoICAQDN5bgfaxM4CJNY

1GsXKG4DnYou6CGO2bZGXVyg8RzNw5E=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Но не понятно как их добавить в к запросу.

Понятно что нужно добавить сертификат, но как его сформировать?

```
req = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

Пробовал такой способ - создать .pfx

```
 opensss pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey privatekey.key -in cert.crt

 X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"cert.pfx");
 req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

Но в результате ошибка создания ssl соединения:

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался. В моём случае оказалось, что сервер, к которому шёл запрос, просто имел самоподписный сертификат. И нужно было всего лишь игнорировать проверку цепочки сертификатов. 
Например так

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

И соответственно используемый сертификат .pfx, создаваемый как указано выше.